# ¿Como puedo validar un JWT desde mi aplicación cliente?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jwt

Estoy consumiendo datos hacia una `api` que fue hecha con `JWT` la cual al autenticarse en ella devuelve un `token` de acceso. Este `token` no se como manejarlo desde mi aplicación cliente, actualmente lo mantengo en una `cookie` la cual le doy un tiempo de caducidad, pero internamente el `token` también tiene un tiempo de vida, entonces no se como manejar estas situaciones.

Si alguien me puede ayudar u orientar con este tema por favor. Mi aplicación cliente esta en asp.net mvc 5.

Answer (score 0):

El token lo puedes mantener en [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) del navegador y olvidarte de la caducidad de las cookies.

Ejemplo:

```
window.sessionStorage["token"] = <token>; // Actual token
windwo.sessionStorage["tokenExpiration"] = <expiration> // Expiration JS date
```

Cuando el usuario cierre sesión lo limpias

```
window.sessionStorage["token"] = undefined;
window.sessionStorage["tokenExpiration"] = undefined;
```

o

```
window.sessionStorage.clear(); // Si ya no necesitas ningún valor del sessionStorage
```

y cuando el usuario cierre el navegador simplemente todo el `sessionStorage` estará vacío al volver a entrar a la web.

El tiempo de vida del token lo puedes manejar en un un [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    if (new Date() > sessionStorage["tokenExpiration"]) {
        // logout
    }
}, 1000);
```